Java Hashcode and equals are equals the object are not equals how come?
I have a custom key. However the test to make them equal is failing.
The hash and equals have been overriden
Can you please give me some clue?
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomKey {

    private int freq;
    private MergerType mergerType;
    private NoiseRemovalType removalNoise;

    public CustomKey(int freq, MergerType mergerType, NoiseRemovalType removalNoise) {
        this.freq = freq;
        this.mergerType = mergerType;
        this.removalNoise=removalNoise;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof CustomKey customKey)) return false;
        return freq == customKey.freq && removalNoise == customKey.removalNoise && mergerType == customKey.mergerType;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(freq, mergerType, removalNoise);
    }

        
    CustomKey customKey=new CustomKey(freq, MergerType.TIME_MERGER, NoiseRemovalType.REMOVE_NOISE);
    CustomKey key=new CustomKey(freq, MergerType.TIME_MERGER, NoiseRemovalType.REMOVE_NOISE);

    System.out.println(key.hashCode());
    System.out.println(key.hashCode()==customKey.hashCode());
    System.out.println(key.equals(customKey));
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(customKey);
    System.out.println(key==customKey);
      

Output

1370597946
true
true
CustomKey{freq=1380, mergerType=TIME_MERGER, removalNoise=REMOVE_NOISE}
CustomKey{freq=1380, mergerType=TIME_MERGER, removalNoise=REMOVE_NOISE}
false


different objects could have the same hashcodes because of collisions, print actual object content to see why they are not equal

I printed toString

mergerType and removalNoise - are they enums or classes?

wait, your equals returns true, reference comparison returns false, which is expected

both are enum type

I remove the line and cast the object with CustomKey customKey = (CustomKey) o; but same behavour
